# Proof of Cartan Theorem B in Hörmander's book

Tags: complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

In the proof of Cartan Theorem B on Hörmander's SCV book (p.199 in third edition), it seems that the following claim is made without justification:

> Let $\Omega$ be a Stein manifold of dimension $n$. Then there exist arbitrarily fine open coverings $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $\Omega$ such that each $U_i$ is a Stein manifold, and more than $N$ ($N>2n$ given) sets in $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ always have an empty intersection.

In the book, the author first chooses $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ with each $U_i$ Stein. Then, to conclude that certain sheaf cohomology groups vanish, the author writes:

> But if the covering is chosen so that more than $N$ sets $U_i$ always have an empty intersection, which is possible if $N>2n$, it is obvious that ...

He then proceeds without explaining why that is possible.

Why is this true? The best I can do is choose $\{U_i\}_i$ to be paracompact, so that on each compact set such an $N$ exists. However, this argument does not give a uniform $N$, let alone a precise bound related to the dimension. Am I missing something?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First, in my opinion, there are better treatments of Cartan's theorem B: The best reference is Grauert and Remmert's _Theory of Stein Spaces_, the second is Gunning and Rossi's _Analytic Functions of Several Complex Variables_. Another good book is _Holomorphic functions of many complex variables_ by Kaup and Kaup. The last reference is very detailed.

Comment: @AmorFati As far as I know, the books you mentioned adopt "the algebraic approach", whereas Hörmander does everything using $L^2$-estimates. Well, I'm definitely going to read the more algebraic books, but in any case Hörmander provides a different perspective on the matter, so it would be nice to understand the proof.

Comment: Of course, definitely understand both. Grauert and Remmert's treatment is very analytic, although they do not use the $L^2$ estimates.